# Ender 3 v2 BLTouch pushing too far in X axis

Tags: creality-ender-3, firmware, bltouch

I'm having issues with my Ender 3 V2 after installing the BLTouch sensor and flashing the firmware. I downloaded the precompiled firmware from Creality's [site](https://forums.creality3dofficial.com/download/ender-series/ender-3-v2/) for the 4.2.2 board. The thing is, everything works fine, but the X-axis seems to be set up too wide (it lets me go up to 245 mm), which results in the head going too far to the right and hitting the extrusion profile - it makes a creaking sound and jumps a few steps. When going from this point back to X coordinate 0, the same happens on the other side. If it was just about me, I would be careful and would not go manually to the edge, but the auto-leveling process measures the board near outer edges and thus goes into this collision (and then it "confuses" the X coordinate).
I tried measuring the steps/mm, but everything seems fine here.

What am I doing wrong? How come the official firmware doesn't work properly? Can I damage the stepper motor by such collisions? If not, I guess at least the carriage belt won't like it in the long run.

Comment: P.s.: If anyone with ender 3 v2 4.2.2 + BlTouch could provide link to correctly working firmware (working with OctoPi ideally) I would be very thankfull.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested: Somewhere (I think it was Reddit) I found that the mainboard has trouble with long filenames. I changed the firmware name from `E3V2-BLTouch-3x3-v4.2.2-v2.0.1.bin` to something like `fw.bin`, flashed again and the issue stopped. WTH.

Comment: If you could [edit] and add the Reddit link that would/could/might be useful.

Comment: I'm sorry, tried and failed. I don't know where I read it, can not find it any more... :(